# Orion Context Broker installation issue

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are trying to install Orion Context Broker in a CentOS-7 virtual machine as recommended in this link: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/install/index.html

When we run the step "yum install contextBroker", an HTTPS 404 error is obtained ([please, see instalation log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTBIE.jpg)). Apparently, the repositories are not available.

We can access to the URL https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/service/rest/repository/browse/el/7/x86_64/release/ from the virtual machine ([see curl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STiPQ.jpg)) and our fiware-release.repo is configured as follows ([see fiware-release.repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLLdA.jpg)):

Please, could you review this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository works (endpoint checks by monitoring), but this path (repodata/***) does not exist and looks like an old cache.
Try to execute:

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
yum install -y contextBroker
```

If not, please, provide additional information about OS (`uname -a`)

Comment: We have cleaned the cache as you indicated us but we obtain the same error.

The OS information is shown as follows:

[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 16:44:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks!

Comment: https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/raw/public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo was updated, can u check with a new version?