# Cannot run the Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

had to move MongoDB on an external VM and therefore reconfigured Orion CB to use Mongo not on localhost but through an IP of external mongoDB (mongoDB was also configured to bind external IPs).
Whenever I try to run Orion CB, it stops, the logs say it has failed:

```
cat: /run/var/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: no such file or directory
```

However, when I create this file - it gives me this:

```
contextBroker dead but pidfile exists.

starting contextBroker....pidfile not found
```

Tried reinstalling it using yum and the latest yum repo config avaliable, but it seems that it is down or not updated? - gives me 404 Not found.

**EDIT 1**
The configuration for yum repo was taken from the Orion official Github:

```
[fiware-release]
name=FIWARE release repository
baseurl=https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/el/7/x86_64/release
enabled=1
protect=0
gpgcheck=0
metadata_expire=30s
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

I have tried multiple ways of running Orion. the most common one is:

```
contextBroker
```

Apart from it, the following were used:

```
contextBroker -ngsiv1Autocast
service contextBroker start
```

**EDIT 2**

Following fgalan's suggestions, here is the response:
[image: contextBroker starting]

Comment: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3328 - issue in Github

Comment: I'd need extra info to understand the situation better. Could you edit your question in order to include 1) the command you use to start CB, 2) the yum.repo you are using? Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with the service script and yum repository appart, note that by default Orion expects the database running in localhost. Thus, if your MongoDB instance runs in a separate server you have to use the `-dbhost` parameter, eg:

```
contextBroker -fg -dbhost 10.1.1.1:27017
```

Extra documentation about the CB CLI can be found [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html).

**EDIT 1:** in the case you have a pid file due to a past invocation with unclean exit (note the msg= in the log trace), then you have to remove it before running CB. For instance:

```
rm -f /tmp/contextBroker.pid
contextBroker -fg -dbhost 10.1.1.1:27017
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It did work finally. Yet still, any comments on yum repository access if you have?

Comment: Regarding yum, I'd recommend to have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426260/orion-context-broker-installation-issue. If the case you have is different, I'd recommend to open a new question similar to that one to get support.