# Error when trying to install Orion Context Broker using yum in CentOS

Tags: fiware-orion

We are trying to install Orion Context broker using the guide from FIWARE (https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/yum/index.html), but when executing the yum command it returns a 404 error. There is another thread with the same error (2020) but still not solve. The problem is not the cache.  This the exact error:

Error:
Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job

- nothing provides /usr/bin/python needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libboost_regex-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgcrypt.so.11()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgcrypt.so.11(GCRYPT_1.2)(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgnutls.so.28()(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_0_0)(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
- nothing provides libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_1_0)(64bit) needed by contextBroker-2.2.0-1.x86_64
  (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: `libgnutls.so.28` is provided by a CentOS 7 package : `gnutls` . .... .... CentOS 8 has `libgnutls.so.30` ......... Your link clearly says CentOS 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orion Context Broker installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426260/orion-context-broker-installation-issue)

Comment: Please edit your question post to add information about the CentOS version in which you are trying to install the packages, i.e. the result of the command `cat /etc/redhat_release` if I'm remembering correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be somekind of mismatch between the packages your are trying to install with `yum` and the packages available in the yum repository configured in your operating system. However, given you haven't provided information about your CentOS operating system version, I cannot provide further help.

However, I see you are trying to install Orion 2.2.0. Note that is a very old version (released in Februrary 2010, almost three years ago!). I'd recommend you to install Orion 3.4.0 (latest version released at the moment of writing this) which [uses CentOS 8 as official operating system](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/build_source/index.html).